# Set awk array on command line?

Tags: shell, awk, options, associative-array

I know the `-v` switch can be used to `awk` on the command line to set the value for a variable.

Is there any way to set values for `awk` associative array elements on the command line?

Something like:

```
awk -v myarray[index]=value -v myarray["index two"]="value two" 'BEGIN {...}'
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. It is not possible to assign non-scalar variables like this on the command line. But it is not too hard to make it.

If you can accept a fixed array name:

```
awk -F= '
  FNR==NR { a[$1]=$2; next}
  { print a[$1] }
' <(echo $'index=value\nindex two=value two') <(echo index two)
```

If you have a file containing the awk syntax for array definitions, you can `include` it:

```
$ cat <<EOF >file.awk
ar["index"] = "value"
ar["index two"] = "value two"
EOF

$ gawk '@include "file.awk"; BEGIN{for (i in ar)print i, ar[i]}'
```

or

```
$ gawk --include file.awk 'BEGIN{for (i in ar)print i, ar[i]}'
```

If you really want, you can run `gawk` with `-E` rather than `-f`, which leaves you with an uninterpreted command line. You can then process those command line options (if it looks like a variable assignment, assign the variable). Should you want to go that route, it might be helpful to look at [ngetopt.awk](https://github.com/joepvd/ngetopt.awk).

Comment: Thanks, I like your first option better than the `gawk` specific one—I almost always stick to POSIX features.  I think I would also use [`printf` in preference to `echo`](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/135943).

Answer (score 2):

With POSIX `awk`, you can't do it.

The *assignment* in form `-v assignment` was defined as:

> An operand that begins with an  or alphabetic character
>   from the portable character set (see the table in XBD Portable
>   Character Set), followed by a sequence of underscores, digits, and
>   alphabetics from the portable character set, followed by the '='
>   character, shall specify a variable assignment rather than a pathname.
>   The characters before the '=' represent the name of an awk variable;
>   if that name is an awk reserved word (see Grammar) the behavior is
>   undefined

That's only allow `awk` variable *name*.

When you set `awk` array element with:

```
myarray[index]=value
```

`myarray[index]` is *lvalue*, not variable *name*. So it's an illegal.

Any variables and fields can be set with:

```
lvalue = expression
```

with *lvalue* can be variables, array with index or fields selector.

Answer (score 0):

How's this?

```
awk _F";" -v M=JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec '$1>=180525 && $1<=180630\
{ m=substr($1,3,2); m=(m-1)*3+1; printf(" %s %d, 20%d\t%s\n",substr(M,m,3),\
substr($1,5,2),substr($1,1,2),$0);}' Filename
```

File delimited with ";". First field is date formated yymmdd. Use string as array. 
Is this cheating?