# Referencing array elements by strings, and initialising arrays in awk

Tags: awk, array

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
awk '
  BEGIN {
    arr[A]=1;
    arr[B]=1;
    arr[C]=1;
    arr[E]=1;
    arr[J]=8;
    arr[Q]=10;
    print arr[J]
  }'
```

the above command outputs the latest set value for `arr['subscript']`,  in this case `10` that is value of `arr[Q]` just before `print` and not `8` that is the value of `arr[J]`.

Also, like in the script above, I don't want to assign values to `arr['A'], arr['B'], arr['C'] and arr['E']` that have same value `1` one line at a time, rather pass an array of subscripts as one of the parameters and common value as the other parameter to a function that handles the logic of assigning them value.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Array indexes are either integers or quoted strings in `awk`.  What you are doing here are using variables that have not yet been initialised.  Their values are therefore empty.

You get the latest value assigned to the array because each assignment is overwriting the previous value.  Using `print arr[""]` would also give you `10` back.

Instead, use strings, as in `arr["A"]=1`.

For your last issue: There is no real facility for initialising an `awk` array from the command line, but you may pass an "encoded" value that you "decode" in your `BEGIN` block (for example) to extract the keys and values for an array.

Example which passes a specially delimited list as a single string and parses it to extract the indexes and values to use:

```
awk -v vals="A=1:B=1:C=1:E=1:J=8:Q=10" '
    BEGIN {
        n = split(vals, v, ":")
        for (i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {
            split(v[i], a, "=")
            arr[a[1]] = a[2]
        }

        print arr["J"]
    }'
```

Using separate keys and values:

```
awk -v keys="A:B:C:E:J:Q" -v vals="1:1:1:1:8:10" '
    BEGIN {
        nk = split(keys, k, ":")
        nv = split(vals, v, ":")

        if (nk != nv) exit 1

        for (i = 1; i <= nk; ++i)
            arr[k[i]] = v[i]

        print arr["J"]
    }'
```

This is quite a limited way of passing an "array" into `awk`, but it works for simple values that one has complete control over.  The examples would break for any data that embeds colons (and equal signs for the 1st example) in the actual data.

Passing data like this also means backslashes in the data will have to be treated specially (`\n` will be a newline, so to pass the two character string `\n`, you would have to use `"\\\n"` or `'\\n'`).

Also related:

- [Set awk array on command line?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/254908)

---

As an aside, you can write a "pure `awk` script" like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN { 
   # some initialisations
}

some_expression { some code }

END {
    # more here
}
```